# solr field normalization for queries without field reference

Tags: solr, lucene, similarity

I am reviewing the similarity calculations performed by the DefaultSimilarity class in Lucene invoked by Solr. Specifically, I am not clear about field normalization as to how its calculated when the Solr query doesn't reference a specific field.

```
norm(t,d) = doc.getBoost() · lengthNorm · ∏ f.getBoost() .... field f in d named as t   

where 
  doc.getBoost() = document's boost specified at index time
  f.getBoost()   = field's boost specified at index time
  lengthNorm     = number of terms/tokens in the field
```

My question is, if a solr query is specified as -

```
/select?q=indian cricket&rows=5&wt=json
```

without reference to a specific field in schema.xml, **how is norm(t,d) calculated? for every field, the term is found in? If so, how 
are these combined?**

Thanks in advance for your insights!

Comment: What is your version of Solr? Are you using a default search field in your `schema.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Fields without a field name will use the `defaultSearchField` setting from the schema, the `df` (default field) query parameter or the `qf` query fields parameter (if using (e)dismax, and the terms will be prefixed with the field name. Each field, term combination for each queried field will then be used to evaluate the norm.

Use the `debugQuery` feature of Solr to see each scored part and how it affects the score.

Comment: Cool - thanks @MatsLindh. That helps. In that case I am curious when multiple fields are searched for the same term, how the field norms are combined for the same term. I will give debugQuery a try, wanted to check before spinning wheels.